# How to map array data into table row in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, fetch-api

I'm just trying to implement a simple React project that retrieves data from an API and iterates over it to create table rows.  I'm not getting any errors, but the data isn't appearing in the table.

```js
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Countries() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all?fields=name,continents,population,flag')
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((apiData) => {
        setData(apiData);
      });
  });
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Continent</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Flag</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((country) => {
            <tr>
              <td>{country.name}</td>
              <td>{country.continents}</td>
              <td>{country.population}</td>
              <td>{country.flag}</td>
            </tr>
          })}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Countries;
```

The data is being fetched:
[image]

Still there are no errors so I'm not sure why the data isn't appearing in the table.
Just returns a blank page.
[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the map function inside the `tbody` tag. You need to add the `return` keyword or use parentheses to wrap the JSX. Also pass an empty array as the second argument to run `useEffect` only once.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import './App.css';

function Countries() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all?fields=name,continents,population,flag')
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((apiData) => {
        setData(apiData);
      });
  }, []); // empty array here
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Continent</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Flag</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map((country) => (
            <tr>
              <td>{country.name}</td>
              <td>{country.continents}</td>
              <td>{country.population}</td>
              <td>{country.flag}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Countries;
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not returning the render `tr` elements, because you wrapped them in curly brackets instead of parentheses. In addition, `name` is an object, and you should use `country.name.common`, and `country.continents` is an array, and you should join it to a single string, or iterate the items:

```
  {data.map(country => (
    <tr key={country.flag}>
      <td>{country.name.common}</td>
      <td>{country.continents.join(', ')}</td>
      <td>{country.population}</td>
      <td>{country.flag}</td>
    </tr>
  ))}
```

In addition, you the `useEffect` doesn't have a dependencies array, which means that it would run on every state change (like setting the state), which would cause another api calls, and set state, which would lead to an infinite loop. Set an empty array `[]` as the dependencies of your `useEffect` to prevent this.

**Example**:

```js
const { useEffect, useState } = React;


function Countries() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('https://restcountries.com/v3.1/all?fields=name,continents,population,flag')
      .then((resp) => resp.json())
      .then((apiData) => {
        setData(apiData);
      });
  }, []);
  
  return (
    <div className="app-container">
      <table>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Continent</th>
            <th>Population</th>
            <th>Flag</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          {data.map(country => (
            <tr key={country.flag}>
              <td>{country.name.common}</td>
              <td>{country.continents.join(', ')}</td>
              <td>{country.population}</td>
              <td>{country.flag}</td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM
  .createRoot(root)
  .render(<Countries />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```